# User can switch on their profile visibility on and off

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I want to be able to let users show and hide the visibility of their 'profile' page in a rails application, indicating their availability to other users.

Currently looking for a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a visibility flag editable by users and filter profile index by it